# Visualizing Bootstrap 4.x Grid Breakpoints during development

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

If you use grid system in Bootstrap 4.x, it can be useful to know exactly which grid breakpoint corresponds to the current viewport width.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by adding the following HTML at the top of your page. When you resize the browser window, the corresponding size will be displayed.

```
<div class="d-block d-sm-none">
    <b>Extra Small</b> &lt;576px
</div>
<div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">
    <b>Small</b> &ge;576px
</div>
<div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">
    <b>Medium</b> &ge;768px
</div>
<div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">
    <b>Large</b> &ge;992px
</div>
<div class="d-none d-xl-block">
    <b>Extra Large</b> &ge;1200px
</div>
```

When you resize your browser window, you can see what the current grid breakpoint is. Remeber to remove this when development is done.

Comment: what ? Why did you do that ? :S